# Heathrow Aiport showers for connecting passengers

Tags: airports, hygiene, lhr

I am arriving at Heathrow Airport Terminal 3 (Air Canada) and departing from Terminal 1 on SAA to SA (layover is 11 hours).  Are there any showers for connecting passengers anywhere (money is no problem), or do I have to leave the airport on a Hoppa Bus and get a day room at one of the local hotels? I don't really want to leave the airport environment!
Cheers!

Comment: In economy or something higher?  Do you have any Star Alliance status?  Roughly what time of day do you arrive?

Comment: In economy. I have Star Alliance, because Air Canada and SAA are in alliance.

Comment: I arrive around 11am from Toronto and depart 9pm for SA.

Comment: I have checked airport lounges, business lounges in terminal 1 have no showers, only lounges in departures in terminal 3, which is no good.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Yeah, can't afford business class from Canada to SAA, totally out my range at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

### Shower at a hotel within Heathrow Airport.

There are the [Hilton Hotel in Terminal 4](http://www3.hilton.com/en/hotels/united-kingdom/hilton-london-heathrow-airport-LHRAPTW/index.html). Accessible via a walkway from Terminal 4. They have [Day Use Rooms](http://www3.hilton.com/en/hotels/united-kingdom/hilton-london-heathrow-airport-LHRAPTW/offers/100057044.htm) available with access to their lounge included.

Sofitel in Terminal 5 which is accessible from within the airport.

[Source](http://www.heathrow-airport-guide.co.uk/hotels.html#T4,5)

### Terminal 3 departures

There are showers in Terminal 3 departures according to the [Heathrow Airport website](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/services-and-facilities/toilets-and-showers):

> Showers are available in the [No.1 Traveller Lounge](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/services-and-facilities/lounges) in Terminal 3 departures (after security) – there is a charge for entry. Facilities may also be available to eligible passengers in the airlines' own lounges.

You need to pay to access the lounge, which can be done online. I don't know if you can do it on arrival.